# How to return value from async function?

Tags: javascript

How to return value from async function?

I have tried this but it does not work:

```
var x;
getText("http://localhost/test/test.html").then(data => {x = data});
 
async function getText(file) { 
   let myObject = await fetch(file);
   let myText = await myObject.json();
   return myText;
     
  }
  alert(x);
```

Comment: That looks okay to me, the only issue is (probably) that the file you're fetching is `html` and not JSON, so you should do `await myObject.text();`

Comment: What about it "doesn't work"? Do you get an error?

Comment: In alert window I get "undefined"

Comment: Use `getText("http://localhost/test/test.html").then(x => { alert(x); })`